Can a kitchen GFCI be at the end of the run?
I would love some direction.
I recently replaced 3 outlets in a 1970's kitchen with GFCIs.  They are all on different circuts as the kitchen wall is basicall where all the wire comes up into the house from the box below.
My question concerns what was a wall outlet.  With a kitchen remodel I opened the wall - made the outlet a junction box.  From the juntion I installed a new GFCI outlet up above counter height.  When the cabinets were installed, I cut into them to expose the junction box in order to bring romex out into a penusula non-GFCI pop-up.
Two specific questions
Am I correct that the pop-up is protected because I have that new GFCI coming off of the junction box?  It is terinated there and wired for protection at that outlet.
Also, Am I required to have conduit inside the back of the cabinets into the island, or just stapling the romex will suffice?
Thank you for your guidance.

The other outlets(pop ups) would need to be wired/get power  from the GFCI receptacle load screws to be protected.

What geographic area are you in, and what electrical code applies? Reason I ask is that you’ve mentioned 14/2, which is inappropriate for many American kitchens.

hank you for the quick response -
So I would need to disconnect the 14/2 (that goes to the pop-up) -- then connect that pop-up (in the junction box) back up the wall to connect to the load screws?
Is there a GFCI outlet option that would I could change to in order to avoid this extra run?

A few notes:

Wire size

All new kitchen counter receptacle circuits must be 20A, and therefore 12 AWG wire. If you have existing kitchen counter receptacle circuits that at 15A then they can use 14 AWG and/or 12 AWG wire.

Line vs. Load

Line refers to the wires coming from the breaker or from the previous receptacle (defined as "previous in the sequence coming from the breaker"). A typical GFCI/receptacle will have only the line screws initially exposed.
Load refers to the wires going from this GFCI to the next device (usually another receptacle). The load screws are normally covered with a piece of tape by the factory to avoid confusion.
The line side is never GFCI-protected (unless you have a GFCI/breaker, but then you wouldn't need GFCI/receptacles, so we'll ignore that possibility). The load side is always GFCI-protected. Which means the sequence is:

Breaker
Possible non-GFCI-protected receptacles. Shouldn't be, generally, on a kitchen circuit, but can be in older installations. Can also be if there are kitchen (or certain related rooms) if the receptacle is more than 6' from all sinks.
GFCI/receptacle
GFCI-protected ordinary receptacles - They are protected because they are connected via the load screws on the GFCI/receptacle.

The actual wiring can be up/down/sideways. The electrons don't care if they "double back" through part of the kitchen from one receptacle to another. (Well, technically they care a little - that's "voltage drop", but within a residential kitchen that is far too little to be concerned about). When adding a new receptacle, that means sometimes it makes sense to wire from A (breaker) to B (existing GFCI/receptacle) to C (new ordinary receptacle) even though physically the layout (i.e., visible in the kitchen without seeing the wires inside the walls) looks like A-C-B. Wire isn't as cheap as it used to be, but in the grand scheme of kitchen remodeling costs it is very, very small.

Junction Boxes must always be accessible. You already know this, but not everyone does.

Cables Inside Cabinets


There seems to be a bit of a debate on this. The question is whether it is "subject to damage". The same cable exposed on a wall would definitely require either conduit or something (e.g., wood) covering it to prevent physical damage. Inside a cabinet there is less concern but still can be some due to pots and pans and other things. My personal opinion is that if the cable is (a) all the way in the back and (b) in a corner, there really isn't much of a problem (that's what my electrician did many years ago for me). But elsewhere in a cabinet the concern about damage is real.
But remember that if you use individual wires then you have to use real conduit. If you use cable then it is only for physical protection: conduit, plywood, other wood strips, pipes (i.e., not rated as conduit but similar) - almost anything will do.

Excellent clarification - thank you kindly!
